# iphone internatiolization

Tags: iphone, internationalization

I need to show a few texts fetched from web in my app. I need to ensure internatiolisation, but i dont want to keep all the resources locally. is it possible that when i hit server from china i get chinese response ? from japan i get japan response ?
what would be the ideal solution ?

Comment: Can you clarify? What exactly do you mean by "I hit server from China"?

Comment: i am in china and is running my application which feteches data from server and should show up automatically in chinese etc .... something like automated, not that i reach china and change locale setting to china and the application loads chinese resources in the local database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to (badly) convert an IP address to a country; search for "geoip". Debian's [libgeoip](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libgeoip1) probably uses [GeoLite Country](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country). Such databases are sometimes outdated or just wrong.

I think it's the wrong behaviour. I want apps to use the language that my phone is set to, not "the language of the country" — maybe I'm a tourist in China and I don't understand Chinese, or maybe I'm in Switzerland (should it be in German, French, or Latin?).

Assuming you'll use *some* localized resources, you can get the list of languages in preferred order with something like this:

```
NSArray * localizations = [[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations];
```

Then pass the list to the server (or simply pass objectAtIndex:0 to the server).

Of course, relying on fetching resources from the server means you'll have to wait for them to load, and means your app doesn't work without an internet connection.